# Enqueued Javascript file gives error: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

The wordpress plugin I am developing is unable to pull in the jquery dependency despite passing it in the third parameter of the wp_enqueue_scripts function. Using the inspect function on google chrome reveals this error: `$ is not a function`, so I am assuming that jquery is not being loaded in correctly. The js file is being reached as 'here' is displayed. Any help would be much appreciated!

PHP admin page:

```
function kent_sidebar_plugin_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('kent_sidebar_process', 
    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'inc/process.js', array('jquery'));
}

function kent_sidebar_add_admin_page(){
    
    add_menu_page('Kent Sidebar Options', 'Kent Sidebar', 'manage_options', 
    'kent_sidebar', 'kent_sidebar_options');
   
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'kent_sidebar_add_admin_page');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'kent_sidebar_plugin_scripts');


function kent_sidebar_options(){
    
    require_once("inc/kent-sidebar-admin.php");
     
}
```

JS file:

```
window.alert("here");

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#editSidebar').onclick(function(){

    var optionVal = $('#sidebarList').find(":selected").text();
    alert(optionVal);

  })

});
```

Comment: Please change the title of this question. In your case, jQuery is being enqueued. Those of us looking for a solution when a script dependency really is missing will not find an answer here.

Comment: @GregPerham I've changed the title of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load your script through a plugin, jQuery is sometimes not defined through the $ you have to manually pass it through a function. So something like this should fix it :

```
window.alert("here");

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('#editSidebar').on("click",function(){

            var optionVal = $('#sidebarList').find(":selected").text();
            alert(optionVal);

        })
    });
```

Also onclick is not a jQuery method, I think you were looking for .on()

Answer (score 3):

Jquery packaged with WordPress comes with Compatibility Mode so that any other JS using $ as alias can run together. You can use jQuery wrapper for adding code with $ eg.

`(function($) {
     // your code with $ 
})( jQuery );`

or you can add `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` at the top of your JS file.